# Why every distro feezes at shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, freeze

I'm using Opensuse Leap 15.3 now, and for some reason this issue is happening with all distros in my computer. When I press to shutdown after a while it freezes and get stuck. Every time it happens I have to always force shutdown. Reboot works fine but shutdown doesn't. If I don't find a solution for this issue, can someone tell me if forcing shutdown will cause damage any to my computer?

[image: freezing during shutdown]

The last line reads:

```
Reached target Power-Off.
```

System Information:

- openSUSE Leap 15.3 64 bits
- KDE Plasma: 5.18.6
- KDE Frameworks: 5.76.0
- Qt: 5.12.7
- kernel: 5.3.18-59.37-default
- 4 × Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz
- RAM: 3,7 GiB
- Nvidia GTX 550 Ti
- kernel module: nvidia

My grub:

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=8
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs acpi=force noefi"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

My BIOS settings

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with `acpi=force`. It looks like it is reaching the point that the kernel sends a singnal to power off the machine and nothing is happening.  That signal is usually sent using ACPI. Have you checked your BIOS to see if ACPI has somehow been turned off or disabled?

Comment: Even without acpi=force i still get the same result. Refresh your page because i made an edit on this post showing my BIOS settings

Comment: Can you tell at which stage it gets stuck? What do you see on the screen/console when / before it gets stuck?

Comment: The first photo is the moment that my pc froze during shutdown

Comment: @aviro I've edited to include the last line in text `Reached target Power-Off.`

Comment: Forcing the poweroff is unlikely to damage the hardware. At that point (as @PhilipCouling says, it seems to be the hardware not responding to power off the machine, but everything is stopped) it is also unlikely to corrupt any data, which would be the concern if a forced power off happened at a random time.

Comment: If you have reached the power-off target then linux shouldn't be doing anything more other than asking the machine to power off, so you shouldn'r do any damage by turning it off yourself. Working out why reboot works but power-off doesn't could be hard. Depending on the age of the machine it might be worth seeing if there is a BIOS update available.

Comment: Then, there is no problem if i force shutdown when it freezes right? Everything is going to be okay with my computer?

Comment: @Weege that's correct.

Comment: Make sure you're running the latest BIOS

Comment: I actually dont know how to update BIOS and I  have heard that updating it might be risky.